# Canvas redraw in multiplayer game

Tags: node.js, html, canvas, socket.io, frame-rate

I'm using node.js and socket.io to create some simple multiplayer bomberman like game. Every time any one player move, everybody's browser will need to redraw everything because that one player's position has changed. I feel this is quite a waste, is there better way to make this work?

I know in FPS game, the canvas is cleared and redraw every fixed interval of time, but I feel this game doesn't have to be a FPS game since nothing need to happen if no one move, am I right?

If you want more detail about how I'm implementing this game, you can read it here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109358/building-a-simple-bomberman-game-with-node-js-and-socket-io

Comment: First of all, you can use multiple canvases to speed it up, eg one canvas for the background of the game and one for the character(s). Also, you can call your redraw function only whenever the character moves, it doesn't look hard to do that.

Comment: Multiple canvases might work, but you could also clear only a portion of the canvas rather than the whole thing.  A `background-image` on whatever element contains the canvas might work as well. I just worry about the composting the browser will have to do to render the DOM with the two canvases on top of one another.  I doubt it would be a huge optimization one way or the other.